# How to change the socket time out value in Jira?

Tags: jira, socket-timeout-exception

We are trying to change the socket timeout in Jira as some of the REST API calls are taking too long to respond due to which we are getting Request Time Out Error.
[image]

For changing it, we tried the following but NONE of them worked:

1. We made changes in the General Configuration settings by following this [article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-system-properties-168002854.html).
2. We followed the following [article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/java-net-sockettimeoutexception-read-timed-while-making-a-request-to-a-remote-server-788958227.html) and changed the `JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS` parameter to increase the socket time and these are our observations:

- When setting the `JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS` to 20000milliseconds (20sec), we found that it fails for the delay above 20sec; rest it is working fine for any value below it.
- When the `JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS` parameter set to any value between 2min to 14min, the delay above 50sec gives error. For the delay uptill 50sec in project creation, it is working fine.

The snapshot of `setenv.sh` file, where we made our changes: [image]

Please suggest how to increase the socket time out so that we do not  get a Request Time Out for a delay of around 2 min.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Please add relevant part of your `setenv.sh` file where you configure it. Also, do you use any web proxy in front of your Jira (nginx, haproxy, apache, IIS, ...)? If so, you have to increase this timeout in the proxy, too. Also, you might want to add a screenshot of the error in question.

Comment: Hi @CraZ, Thanks for the suggestions. We are not using any proxy to access Jira.

Answer (score 0):

If you use unproxied access to your Jira (i.e. via Tomcat distributed together with Jira), then you will have to change the timeout also in the Tomcat configuration: `<jira-install>/conf/server.xml`.

There's Tomcat's connector configuration:

```xml
<Connector port="8080" connectionTimeout="20000" ...
                                          ^^^^^
```

**Notes:**

- Also feel free to contact official Atlassian Support if you have paid subscription.
- Also take a look into logs to find out why project creation takes so much time and times-out (it's not normal, project creation is a matter of a second).

Comment: Hi @CraZ, thanks for the suggestion but I tried it out and it did not work for me. Do you have any other suggestions on how we can change the socket time out in Jira?

Comment: Sorry, no further ideas at this moment. You might need to each out official Atlassian Support.